# MacOS Python script executable

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, executable, usb-flash-drive

I made a long GUI Tkinter program for a research study I am doing. I want to make it so the program opens (without the edit shell) when you double click an icon on a **flash drive**. I have tried all sorts of things with chmod +x and whatnot (I really am not a professional coder as you can tell). Can someone help me? I coded it all on my Macbook, but I want to move the executable program to a flash drive so that I can run in it my lab.

Let me know if you need any sample codes. I really have made no progress in making this executable.

Comment: You can try and use [pyintstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) for this

Comment: Hey! thanks! I am unfamiliar with pyintstaller, is there a good guide to learn it?

Comment: Try this: https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: Its not really difficult the official docs are a good way to learn it.

Comment: I will get back to you @Avijeet and let you know! You are helping me immensely!